# Symfony foreign keys (How can i edit them ?)

Tags: symfony, doctrine, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have a little problem i don't know why i can't edit my foreign key ($idProfile) but i can edit an other value from the database :

I can change the value enable for exemple but not the idProfile when i try to change it i have this error : "An instance of Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface must be injected in FOS\RestBundle\View\ViewHandler to render templates." don't know if that can help thx for help guys :p

In general : I just want to know how can i edit my $id_profile to link it with my profile entity

my Profile controller :

```
 /**
 * Creates a new profile entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new/{id}", name="profile_new")
 */
public function newProfileAction(Request $request, User $user)
{

    $loggedAs = $this->getUser();
    $username =  $loggedAs->getUsername();

    $profile = new Profile();
    $form = $this->createForm(ProfileType::class, $profile);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $profile->setLastConnexion(new \DateTime('now'));
        $profile->setCreatedAccount(new \DateTime('now'));

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($profile);
        $em->flush();

        $user->setEnabled('1');
        $user->setIdLocation($profile->getId());
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();



        return $this->redirectToRoute('user_list');
    }

    return $this->render('admin/user/new_profile.html.twig', array(
        'profile' => $profile,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'username' => $username,
    ));
}
```

My userEntity :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
* User
*
* @ORM\Table(name="user", uniqueConstraints=
{@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="user_id_uindex", columns={"id"}), 
@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="user_username_uindex", columns=
{"username"})}, indexes={@ORM\Index(name="user_profile_id_fk", 
columns={"id_profile"}), @ORM\Index(name="user_localisation_id_fk", 
columns={"id_location"})})
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
* @UniqueEntity("username", groups={"Default", "Patch"})
*/
class User implements UserInterface
{
const ROLE_USER = 'ROLE_USER';
const ROLE_ADMIN = 'ROLE_ADMIN';

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 * @Serializer\Groups({"Default", "Deserialize", "user_detail"})
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=32)
 * @Serializer\Groups({"Default", "Deserialize", "user_detail"})
 */
protected $username;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255)
 * @Serializer\Groups({"Deserialize", "user_detail"})
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *     pattern="/(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]).{7,}/",
 *     message="Password must be seven characters long and contain at least one digit code, upper case, and lower case letter!",
 *     groups={"Default", "Patch"}
 * )
 */
protected $password;

/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="enabled", type="boolean", nullable=false)
 */
protected $enabled = '1';

/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Localisation
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Localisation")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_location", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
protected $idLocation;

/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Profile
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Profile")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_profile", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
protected $idProfile;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="idUserOne")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="friend",
 *   joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_user_one", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   },
 *   inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_user_two", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   }
 * )
 */
protected $idUserTwo;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Place", inversedBy="idUserInvited")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="list_invited",
 *   joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_user_invited", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   },
 *   inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_place_invited", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   }
 * )
 */
protected $idPlaceInvited;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Place", mappedBy="idUserPresent")
 */
protected $idPlacePresent;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Place", inversedBy="idUserPlace")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_place",
 *   joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_user_place", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   },
 *   inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_place_place", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   }
 * )
 */
protected $idPlacePlace;

/**
 * @var array
 * @ORM\Column(type="simple_array", length=200)
 * @Serializer\Exclude()
 */
protected $roles;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->idUserTwo = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->idPlaceInvited = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->idPlacePresent = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->idPlacePlace = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @param int $id
 */
public function setId(int $id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

/**
 * @return string|null
 */
public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->username;
}

/**
 * @param string $username
 */
public function setUsername(string $username)
{
    $this->username = $username;
}

/**
 * @return string|null
 */
public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * @param string $password
 */
public function setPassword(string $password)
{
    $this->password = $password;
}

/**
 * @return bool
 */
public function isEnabled()
{
    return $this->enabled;
}

/**
 * @param bool $enabled
 */
public function setEnabled(bool $enabled)
{
    $this->enabled = $enabled;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getIdLocation()
{
    return $this->idLocation;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $idLocation
 */
public function setIdLocation($idLocation)
{
    $this->idLocation = $idLocation;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getIdProfile()
{
    return $this->idProfile;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $idProfile
 */
public function setIdProfile($idProfile)
{
    $this->idProfile = $idProfile;
}

/**
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getIdUserTwo()
{
    return $this->idUserTwo;
}

/**
 * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $idUserTwo
 */
public function setIdUserTwo(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $idUserTwo)
{
    $this->idUserTwo = $idUserTwo;
}

/**
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getIdPlaceInvited()
{
    return $this->idPlaceInvited;
}

/**
 * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $idPlaceInvited
 */
public function setIdPlaceInvited(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $idPlaceInvited)
{
    $this->idPlaceInvited = $idPlaceInvited;
}

/**
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getIdPlacePresent()
{
    return $this->idPlacePresent;
}

/**
 * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $idPlacePresent
 */
public function setIdPlacePresent(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $idPlacePresent)
{
    $this->idPlacePresent = $idPlacePresent;
}

/**
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getIdPlacePlace()
{
    return $this->idPlacePlace;
}

/**
 * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $idPlacePlace
 */
public function setIdPlacePlace(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $idPlacePlace)
{
    $this->idPlacePlace = $idPlacePlace;
}

/**
 * Returns the roles granted to the user.
 *
 * <code>
 * public function getRoles()
 * {
 *     return array('ROLE_USER');
 * }
 * </code>
 *
 * Alternatively, the roles might be stored on a ``roles`` property,
 * and populated in any number of different ways when the user object
 * is created.
 *
 * @return (Role|string)[] The user roles
 */
public function getRoles()
{
    return $this->roles;
}

/**
 * @param array $roles
 */
public function setRoles(array $roles)
{
    $this->roles = $roles;
}

/**
 * Returns the salt that was originally used to encode the password.
 *
 * This can return null if the password was not encoded using a salt.
 *
 * @return string|null The salt
 */
public function getSalt()
{
    // TODO: Implement getSalt() method.
}

/**
 * Removes sensitive data from the user.
 *
 * This is important if, at any given point, sensitive information like
 * the plain-text password is stored on this object.
 */
public function eraseCredentials()
{
    // TODO: Implement eraseCredentials() method.
}
```

}

some screen of data base : [https://ibb.co/iCSnWy
p
[https://ibb.co/cZZedd
p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you defined profile as type of  \AppBundle\Entity\Profile this is the right way to work with doctrine. No to understand what is the difference in your entities and your database...
In the entities you need to set the entity not the id. Doctrine will then passt the id in the database, and when you get the entity from doctrine it will parse the id to an entity.
This means:

```
 $user->setIdLocation($profile); //<-- set the entity
$profil =  $user->getIdLocation(); // get the profile not the id
```